# What do these Fortran (90) statements do?

Tags: syntax, fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I have run into the follow code and I do not understand it. What does it do?

```
A(*)

do n=(k,k-1,j+1-k)
```

Comment: I don't know a lick of Fortran, and my initial guess for the second line of code was correct (Hint: loop).  As for the first, I'd need more context.  Have you actually tried looking at any documentation?

Answer (score 3):

`A(*)` looks like (part of) the declaration of an 'assumed-size array'; the typical use of this would be in the declaration of a dummy argument to a procedure.  Distinguish carefully between assumed-size and 'automatic' arrays.  Assumed-size arrays are deprecated in modern Fortran but common in FORTRAN77 and earlier variations.

`do n=(k,k-1,j+1-k)` looks like a syntactically-incorrect loop statement.  The correct form would be `do n=k,k-1,j+1-k` which loops over the range `[k,k-1]` in strides of size `j+1-k`.

Comment: thanks . If it would like a for loop, which part would initialization , condition and increment/decrement ?

Comment: Sorry for wrong do statement. Basically I need to convert a gauss algorithm from fortran 90 to c/c++.

REAL:: A(*) -------- ???
.....
DO 30 K=K1+IM,NNR,IM ---- ???

.......

Comment: These are both more Fortran 77, but I really recommend you to read sime documentation these are very basic things and you must know them well to be succesfull. You may encounter much more subtle things.

Comment: @liza5757: why convert a working routine from Fortran to C/C++ ?  It's never been easier to call Fortran routines from those languages.  Google around for 'Fortran interoperability with C'.

Comment: :( . but i have to do for my final thesis of university.

Comment: @liza5757 - Then you have some learning to do before you graduate, don't you?

Comment: Don't tell me to learn Fortran. at least ! If you know the answer, tell me please. Please avoid personal topic !

Comment: @liza5757: you've been told the answer. Comments on SO are often full of useless and unsought 'advice'.  Part of the price of using the site is putting up with them, there's nothing offensive about what Jack suggested, just ignore it.